# Unable to load plug-in assembly error with CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

for some time now our project team has been getting "Unable to load plug-in assembly" errors intermittently when registering plugins via the plugin registration tool to CRM Online. Has anyone got any suggestions on the cause and the fix to this error? The full stack trace is below.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that registration sometimes fails for a plugin assembly and when retried succeeds for the very same assembly/version?

Comment: Don't post an image of the error.  It's not searchable!  Actually paste the error text as code, or a quote

Comment: Wild guess...is assembly signed? See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949088)

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen you are 100% correct that is exactly what is happening

Comment: @Daryl I completely agree and normally I would copy and paste error details. This time the error details caused validation errors when submitting the question therefore I added the screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @keerz the assembly is signed.

Comment: @user3845056 Are you using any external assemblies ? Or `ILMERGE` ?